# DD4T.ContentModel.XmlSerializers dll is missing in DD4T.Model 2.2.3 NuGet package

Tags: dd4t-2

Whenever I download `DD4T.Model 2.2.3` I do not see `DD4T.ContentModel.XmlSerializers.dll`. I have even tried multiple times in last 10 days.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 versions and NuGet Package Manager 4.6.0

I'm installing the Nuget package from following source:

[image]

Downloaded package
[image]

Please verify if this NuGet package needs to be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've downloaded the package straight from nuget.org (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DD4T.Model/2.2.3) and opened it in the Nuget Package Explorer. This is what I see:

[image: screenshot of the package in Nuget Package Explorer]

As you can see, it does contain the DLL in question.

Are you certain that you are getting the package from Nuget itself? Or is there a private repository in play that may contain a corrupted version of the package, somehow?

Comment: Thanks @Quirijn for check this. I have added the screen shots in question to highlight the package source and downloaded files.

Comment: Have you downloaded the package from nuget.org with the browser? That's what I did and it does contain the dll..

Comment: Your are right If download the nupkg file and install via Package Manager, then I can see the missing DLL.

Comment: In that case, can you remove the DD4T.Model.2.2.3 folder from your packages folder and restore the package again?

Comment: Yes, in local set up this is fine. wondering how this will work when TeamCity downloads the packages during build activity. I will verify and report back if I see any issues there.